# How to implement prepersist and preupdate with spring-data-dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am save information like createdBy and updatedBy but `@prePersist` and `@preUpdate` is not working

Answer (score 0):

If your plan is using prePersist and preUpdate to update the timestamp just as my case. You can use [DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp.html)